# Jquery : How to Varying modal content based on trigger button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Is there another way to varying modal with Picture based on trigger button?

If I have the trigger button which contains the picture:

```
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewModal" data-picture="<?php echo $user->getPicture(); ?>"></button>
```

What's the best approach to fetch and show the picture on the modal?

This is my picture field in that modal:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <center>
      <img src="**(SHOULD I PUT THE PICTURE IN HERE?)**" name="picture" width="140" height="140" border="0" class="img-circle">
    </center>
 </div>
```

And this is the javascript who handle the modal :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#ViewModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
   var picture = button.data('picture')

   var modal = $(this)
   modal.find('.modal-body img[name="picture"]').val(picture)
   })

</script>
```

**Note : I can not fetch the picture in modal with this line of code**

Is there another way to varying modal with Picture based on trigger button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should declare your modal html somewhere in the footer of the page, so you have more control and more ease in displaying your image.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_image" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">      
<div class="modal-body">
<center>
<img src="" id="picture" width="140" height="140" border="0" class="img-circle">
</center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then you just change the src attribute of the picture element from your function.

```
var picture = button.data('picture')    
$('#picture').attr('src',picture);
```